# Joomla: How to control module display on pages not in menus, such as the default login page

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-component, joomla-module

I am trying to control what modules are displayed on pages that are generated by components, such as when a user logs in or tries to log in. The pages are not in a menu structure so I can't unpublish modules the usual way.

Continuing with the login example, the url would be "www.mysite.co.uk/index.php/component/users/?view=login"

How do I control module publication on such pages, I'd prefer not to have to use overrides.

Joomla v2.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Joomla Advanced Module Manager - JED Link [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307). It gives you a lot more control than the usual methods for setting modules on menu pages - including "Option to show modules on all pages, except the selected menu items" - i.e. show it on all pages except the login page etc.